# XMP toolbox for Matlab

Tags: matlab, xmp

Has anyone ever heard of something that might facilitate the work with [XMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) metadata in Matlab?

For instance, EXIF metadata can be read simply by using the `exifread` command -

```
output = exifread(filename);
```

I've found [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1451988) thread, but it seems to be dead.

---

Currently I am thinking about the following options:

1. Writing MEX file using C++ XMP SDK
2. Calling Java routines using JAVA  XMP SDK

To summarize, the question is:
**Do you have any idea on how XMP can be read/written in Matlab?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The best way is to download [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and any [Matlab JSON parser](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20565). It is possible to extract it from **any** file format, including `.DNG`, `.XMP`, `.JPEG`, `.TIFF`.

Step 1: Extract the info into temporary JSON file by using

```
system(['exiftool -struct -j ' fileName '>'  tempFile]);
```

Step 2: Call the JSON parser on the tempFile
Step 3: You have the data in Matlab struct.

Answer (score 0):

XMP is just XML, so you can use any MATLAB XML toolbox.  My personal favourite is [xml_io_tools](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools).

---

If you want to use the SDK to avoid having to manually interpret what bits of the XML means, then of your two options the Java one sounds preferable.  Calling Java from MATLAB is [straightforward](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html), and you avoid the hassle of building things that MEX entails.

Comment: You are right of course. But that means doing a lot of custom parsing. For example, XMP defines data structures like Rectangles (And Units). It would be nice to have a parser that knows more about the underlying format.

Comment: To be more precise - XMP uses a subset of RDF and comes with a bunch of pre-built templates for data storage such as IPTC and Dublin Core.