# How to write an image with EXIF data (Matlab/C++)

Tags: c++, image, matlab, exif

How can I write an image including EXIF data?

I am using Matlab and C++, any solution will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375057/xmp-toolbox-for-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to help out others:

I found a program called **ExifTool by Phil Harvey**. it is used to change, write and even copy exif data between files. 
it can run from the command line, so I can run it from matlab.

Here is a link for you all to enjoy:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: This is not a very clean solution as it will require you to save an image twice; once for writing the image and once for writing the metadata with the exiftool.